# Sanitise user input in Camping

Tags: ruby, web-applications, camping

In Camping, how do I sanitise user input?

```
@input.user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "sanitise"?

If you're using ActiveRecord to insert/query data, sanitising should be handled for you:

```
class UserX
  def get
    @user = User.where(:name => @input.name).first
  end
end
```

If you're thinking about HTML sanitising, Markaby should handle it for you:

```
def user
  h1 @input.name     # This is automatically escaped
  h1 { @input.name } # This is not escaped
end
```

Comment: Thanks Magnus. My app was letting users post arbitrary HTML. In the process of investigating, I updated all the gems and the issue fixed itself. Sadly I have no record of which packages were being used because this was on old Heroku bamboo, so no `Gemfile.lock`.